# Woocommerce List All Previously Ordered Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set up a page that a user can go on and they can see all the products they have bought in the standard Woocommerce format so they can add a number of them to the cart.

I've tried this but only 1 is showing up at each time annoyingly:

```
<ul class="products">
[insert_php]
        $user_id        = get_current_user_id();
        $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
        $customer_email = $current_user->email;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
                $loop->the_post(); 
                $_product = get_product( $loop->post->ID );
                if (wc_customer_bought_product($customer_email, $user_id,$_product->id)){
                     woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                }
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
[/insert_php]
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

Comment: Apologies, I'm using a plugin that allows me to put PHP in Wordpress pages. Replace [insert_php] with <?php and [/insert_php] with ?>

Comment: what's wrong in this code is that you will get 12 products per page but only display those that are bought by a user. So, if by chance in that page, there's only one bought product, then that would be displayed and no other products. And if by chance in that page, no products where bought, then nothing is displayed.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to use those plugins that allow you to put PHP into page content. Those plugins are big security risks. Use shortcodes instead. They are harder to get a grapple on, but easier than fixing your reputation if your site gets hacked.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong in your code is that you will get 12 products per page but only display those that are bought by a user. So, if by chance in that page, there's only one bought product, then that would be displayed and no other products. And if by chance in that page, no products where bought, then nothing is displayed. Try this:

```
<ul class="products">
[insert_php]
        global $wpdb;

        $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
        $customer_email = $current_user->user_email;
        $customer_data = array( $customer_email );
        $statuses      = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

        $result = $wpdb->get_col( "
                SELECT im.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS i ON p.ID = i.order_id
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS im ON i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
                WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $statuses ) . "' )
                AND pm.meta_key IN ( '_billing_email', '_customer_user' )
                AND im.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
                AND im.meta_value != 0
                AND pm.meta_value IN ( '" . implode( "','", $customer_data ) . "' )
            " );
        $product_ids = array_map( 'absint', $result );

        if ( !empty( $product_ids ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'product',
                'post__in'          => $product_ids,
                'posts_per_page'    => 12
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
                    $loop->the_post(); 
                     woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                endwhile;
            } else {
                echo __( 'No products found' );
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
[/insert_php]
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

The sql code part is taken from WooCommerce [`wc_customer_bought_product`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_customer_bought_product.html#190-240) function. What this function does is get all the products bought by a given email address, resulting data as an array of product ids. After getting all the products, your given product id will be tested if it's in the those products. So yeah, minus the testing part, that's all we need.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working (WP 4.8, WooCommerce 3.1.0, Insert PHP 1.3).

I wanna clear one moment:

If you client **buy one product more than time**, anyway you got **one** product in list.

Big chance that problem is with testing data. Can you check again, please.