# Display Woocommerce purchased simple products by customer

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am displaying the purchased products in their account page by user logged-in. I implemented it using the instructions on this link [Woocommerce List All Previously Ordered Products](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44438775/). I'd like to only display the purchased products with product type "simple" instead of displaying all purchased products.

I used the below query:

```
global $wpdb;

$current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
$customer_email = $current_user->user_email;
$customer_data = array( $customer_email );
$statuses      = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

$result = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT im.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS i ON p.ID =  i.order_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS im ON i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
    WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $statuses ) . "' )
    AND pm.meta_key IN ( '_billing_email', '_customer_user' )
    AND im.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
    AND im.meta_value != 0
    AND pm.meta_value IN ( '" . implode( "','", $customer_data ) . "' )
" );
```

What will be the right sql query to be inserted to it in order to display only the products with product type "simple"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to restrict this query to simple product only with the following code, Where we do a sub "taxonomy query" based on `product_type` Woocommerce taxonomy *(that manage the product types)* for the term slug `simple` *(simple products)*:

```
global $wpdb;

$current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
$customer_email = $current_user->user_email;
$customer_data = array( $customer_email );
$statuses      = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

$result = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT im.meta_value 
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm 
        ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS i 
        ON p.ID =  i.order_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS im 
        ON i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
    WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $statuses ) . "' )
    AND pm.meta_key IN ( '_billing_email', '_customer_user' ) 
    AND im.meta_key = '_product_id'
    AND im.meta_value IN (
        SELECT tr.object_id 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt 
            ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t 
            ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_type' 
        AND t.slug = 'simple'
    )
    AND pm.meta_value IN ( '" . implode( "','", $customer_data ) . "' )
    GROUP BY im.meta_value
" );

// The raw output (testing
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

Tested and works.